# Notch more than 25% deep on a load bearing wall stud. Help!

Tags: walls, mounting, studs, load-bearing

I hired someone (so much regret) to mount a tv for me and they notched the studs of the load bearing wall for the cabling. I don't have a picture of the notch but I have a picture of the mounting and the dry wall before it went up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSjtC.jpg

On the last picture you can see putty on the left hand side and that is where the notch is. This notch is on 4 studs that are together side by side. Studs are 5.5 inches deep. The notch is uneven, 2 inches max depth and 1 and 3/8 inches minimum depth.

This is a newly constructed multiunit building in Bay Area, CA. That tv was mounted on a second floor of a wall that starts on the first and goes to the 3rd floor. There is a bedroom right above the living room where the wall is.

What do I do?

Comment: The pictures do not reveal enough to say whether the wall is bearing or not. There is a chance the wall is not bearing. Bearing walls hold stuff up, the pictures only show the bottom. Also the fact that the studs are 2X6 help, with a 2" deep notch, they are still, in worst case scenario a 2X4

Comment: Was this done while the building was going on? I am thinking an inspector would have caught this if this was done while the rest of the unit was being built. The inspector would have known if this was a bearing wall. Just because a wall has a lot of studs in it and the are stacked up one over another, does not mean bearing walls, if that train of thought was carried through, all stairwell walls are bearing, Typically not the case. Do you have a picture of the bare frame ceiling?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. However this wall is across 3 floors. I don't know if it is a continuous wall but feels like it is. There is a bedroom right above the living room and a garage right below it with a wall at a very similar location.

This was done after the building was done. I got these pictures from another resident who has the same floor plan as mine. The studs locations could be slightly different.

Comment: when I go to that link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSjtC.jpg ) there is only a single picture of a tv against a wall.  Can you fix your link to go to the complete set of pictures?

Answer (score 1):

user71123,
With the 2x6's notched uneven, you won't get optimal support for your tv. The     1 3/8" notch is fine, but I wouldn't go deeper. You'll want to sister in (along side) your existing studs with 30" 2x6 blocks placed above and below the notched studs. In other words your sister blocks should be placed so the notched part of your existing studs hit center of sister blocks. Then you can cut new notches for your tv mount.

I know it may be a lot of work since the drywall is already hung. The only other advice I can give is to return your tv mount, and buy one that's suitable for hanging tv's without notching, unless your local codes won't permit that type of tv mount. If permitted, so you can use a mount without notching, then you'll have to adjust placement on other studs or even a different wall. Good luck

Comment: From the picture, the notch is to the left and below where the TV is hung, so I assume the notching was done to allow room for the cabling to run (and not to actually support the TV).

Comment: Robert Nubel, you may be right about the notching for cabling, but that seems very excessive to go so deep. My thinking was for a sub mounted plate to accomodate the tv mount. Thanks fo the imput.

Comment: The notching is for the cabling. Do I still have to go for the sister studd? Any idea how much this is going to cost me to get done by a licensed professional?

Comment: It would be a good idea to go with the sister studs since it is load bearing ,and re-notch about an inch deep x 3/4" for cabling. I can't advise you on prices in your area, but I'd say your in the neighborhood of $400.00.

Comment: I am guessing they went so deep on the notch so they would not need a plate over the wires (1-1/4" required) when I run a remodel if I have to notch I go shallow and use steel plates to protect the wires, on new construction I drill the holes.